# Extract graphics from an icon font

Tags: vector-graphics, icon-fonts

Anyone knows how to extract the graphics in a vector format out of an [icon font](https://github.com/showcases/icon-fonts) such as those up on github?

For example how would you convert this **Font Awesome SVG:**

```
<glyph unicode="&#xf007;" horiz-adv-x="1408" d="M1408 131q0 -120 -73 -189.5t-194 -69.5h-874q-121 0 -194 69.5t-73 189.5q0 53 3.5 103.5t14 109t26.5 108.5t43 97.5t62 81t85.5 53.5t111.5 20q9 0 42 -21.5t74.5 -48t108 -48t133.5 -21.5t133.5 21.5t108 48t74.5 48t42 21.5q61 0 111.5 -20t85.5 -53.5t62 -81 t43 -97.5t26.5 -108.5t14 -109t3.5 -103.5zM1088 1024q0 -159 -112.5 -271.5t-271.5 -112.5t-271.5 112.5t-112.5 271.5t112.5 271.5t271.5 112.5t271.5 -112.5t112.5 -271.5z" />
```

to **HTML SVG?**

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000" ><path transform="scale(0.1,0.1)" d="M1408 131q0 -120 -73 -189.5t-194 -69.5h-874q-121 0 -194 69.5t-73 189.5q0 53 3.5 103.5t14 109t26.5 108.5t43 97.5t62 81t85.5 53.5t111.5 20q9 0 42 -21.5t74.5 -48t108 -48t133.5 -21.5t133.5 21.5t108 48t74.5 48t42 21.5q61 0 111.5 -20t85.5 -53.5t62 -81 t43 -97.5t26.5 -108.5t14 -109t3.5 -103.5zM1088 1024q0 -159 -112.5 -271.5t-271.5 -112.5t-271.5 112.5t-112.5 271.5t112.5 271.5t271.5 112.5t271.5 -112.5t112.5 -271.5z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little project i made to extract svg icons of svg fonts https://github.com/nfroidure/svgfont2svgicons

Answer (score 0):

This [JSX script](https://github.com/somerandomdude/Iconic/tree/master/scripts/vector%20creation) can export an iconfont to SVG files. I don't know where you run it though, probably an Adobe app.